# Problem with fill between option in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I have a problem with fill between option when I try to use it for more than one plot. Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.1]
        \addplot[name path=f,domain=-.15:1.05,blue, draw=none] {x^2};
        %\addplot[name path=g, domain=.15:1.05,blue, draw=none] {x^3}; 
        \path[name path=g] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);

        \addplot [
            fill=orange, 
            opacity=0.5
        ]
        fill between[
            of=f and g,
            soft clip={domain=0:1},
        ];

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.1]
        \addplot[name path=f,domain=-.15:1.05,blue, draw=none] {x^2};
        \addplot[name path=g, domain=.15:1.05,blue, draw=none] {x^3}; 
        %\path[name path=g] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);

        \addplot [
            fill=orange, 
            opacity=0.5
        ]
        fill between[
            of=f and g,
            soft clip={domain=0:1},
        ];

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 

    \end{document}
```

and here is the output

[image]

As you can see, it works fine for the first picture but it fails to work for the second one. If I remove the first picture, then the second one works fine as well.

[image]

Comment: Does this persist if you change the names of the paths in the second plot? Also please try to make your examples independent from your data files.

Comment: It works when I change the names of the paths. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Does this need an additional bug report or you take it from here?

Comment: I edited the question so that the plots are independent of the data files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a software defect. A software upgrade of pgfplots to version 1.11 or 1.12 will fix it (tested together with PGF 3.0.0).